# How to find why my computer is freezing?

Tags: windows-10, freeze

A few days ago, without any previous issue my windows 10 computer started to freeze after some random time being used.
Moments before, the mouse slows down, and then the image freezes and I cannot toggle the keyboard LEDs, as it stopped responding.

I checked in the event viewer but it doesn't seem to have any information.
I cleaned the dust since it had a good amount but the issue persists.

Any idea what can be happening, how to find out and how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: A reasonable suggestion here would be to run a complete set of computer manufacturer's hardware diagnostic tests including memory.  Something may have overheated in the dust.

Comment: Also, use DISM and SFC to check and repair any Windows issues.

Comment: If possible use windows taskmanager to see if there is a spike in cpu or disk utilization during these slowdowns.

Comment: @BlindSpots following your advice the other day I noticed it slowed down when there was a spike of 100% memory usage. However I don't understand it since I was always demanding more than I do now, so it doesn't make sense that it's failing now. Sometimes is just with a Netflix tab open nothing else.

Comment: The other day it froze 3 times in less than 1h so I open the task manager and I set it to stay always on top. Then it didn't freeze while I used it :P

Comment: I remember that recently I run out of disk space, later I freed some space, but is it possible that Win10 disabled some virtual memory that uses hard drive because of running out of space, and now something that improved the performance might be disabled?